# Setting up JanusGraph

Tags: apache-spark, solr, docker-compose, janusgraph, scylla

I'm new to JanusGraph. Can somebody help me edit this docker-compose file to use ScyllaDB instead of Cassandra and Apache Solr instead of Elasticsearch? Also does Apache Spark get installed automatically or do I have to also put it into the docker-compose file?

Thank you.

```
services:
  janusgraph:
    image: janusgraph/janusgraph:latest
    container_name: jce-janusgraph
    environment:
      JANUS_PROPS_TEMPLATE: cassandra-es
      janusgraph.storage.backend: cql
      janusgraph.storage.hostname: jce-cassandra
      janusgraph.index.search.hostname: jce-elastic
    ports:
      - "8182:8182"
    networks:
      - jce-network
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "bin/gremlin.sh", "-e", "scripts/remote-connect.groovy"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 3
  cassandra:
    image: cassandra:3
    container_name: jce-cassandra
    ports:
      - "9042:9042"
      - "9160:9160"
    networks:
      - jce-network
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.6.0
    container_name: jce-elastic
    environment:
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "http.host=0.0.0.0"
      - "network.host=0.0.0.0"
      - "transport.host=127.0.0.1"
      - "cluster.name=docker-cluster"
      - "xpack.security.enabled=false"
      - "discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes=1"
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    networks:
      - jce-network

networks:
  jce-network:
volumes:
  janusgraph-default-data:
```

Edit: I've successfully switched Cassandra to Scylla

```
version: "3"

services:
  graph:
    image: janusgraph/janusgraph:0.5.2
    environment:
      JANUS_PROPS_TEMPLATE: cassandra-es
      janusgraph.storage.backend: cql
      janusgraph.storage.hostname: db
      janusgraph.index.search.hostname: index
    ports:
      - "8182:8182"
      - "8184:8184"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - index
  db:
    image: scylladb/scylla:4.2.1
    ports:
      # REST API
      - "10000:10000"
      # CQL ports (native_transport_port)
      - "9042:9042"
      # Thrift (rpc_port)
      - "9160:9160"
      # Internode
      - "7000:7000"
      - "7001:7001"
      # JMX
      - "7199:7199"
      # Prometheus monitoring
      - "9180:9180"
      - "9100:9100"
    volumes:
      - ./data/db/data:/var/lib/db
  index:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.6.0
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - http.host=0.0.0.0
      - transport.host=127.0.0.1
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    volumes:
     - ./data/index/data:/usr/share/index/data
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so Scylla installation is fine now. Regarding Spark, you'll need to install it yourself or add another container for it.

Comment: I thought so. How can I switch Elasticsearch to Apache Solr tho?

Comment: I don't think there is a cassandra-solr in https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph-docker#properties-template templates, nor in properties files


to me it seems manually it can be done and all those storage backends are supported, 


but for docker to support it you would need to add templates for properties first